# Swapping and removing numbers within a randomized Python guessing game

Tags: python

Within a python program, I need to simulate a basic game. Within this game, I need to randomize a hiding spot using a number between 1-3 as part of a simulated game:

```
def coin_places(): 
    return random.randrange(1,4)
```

I then take this random number and put it into the game, seeing if the simulated guess is correct:

```
hide_spot = coin_places()
print(hide_spot)
guess = random.randrange(1,4)
print(guess)


def game():
    if guess == hide_spot: 
        return True
    elif guess != hide_spot:
        return False
    else:
        return game(guess)
```

However, where I'm stumped is, I've been tasked with creating a caveat where one wrong hiding spot is removed, and the program must swap the remaining two guess numbers.

For example, the ramdom output is guess = 2 and hide_spot = 2, so the number 3 or 1 needs to be removed, and guess will be swapped with what is left, let's say from 2 to 1. Each the caveat and original values are outputted as percent chances (just as background, I'm able to write that part)

I can't seem to be able to find any examples of this kind of problem elsewhere, and any help would be greatly appreciated!

To be a bit more clear essentially I need to:

- Create a simulated number of games, from user input
- Create the number of spots and designate one as the hiding spot.
- Create the parameters of the normal game, simulating user guess
- Add another technique, which will produce its own results, where one wrong hiding spot is removed, and the program must swap the remaining two guess numbers.
- Output the chances of success of each technique as percentages

Thanks a bunch for any help or consideration!

Comment: Have you tried creating a list of the possible guesses? Once you have a tangible object with which to work, removing an element should be easy. Then the next hiding spot can be selected based on a random number of the available indices of the remaining list.

Comment: Adding to the other comment, you need to describe, in English, the steps you might take to implement this algorithm. You've sort of done that here, but you need to break things down into smaller pieces. Don't worry about the code. Just describe the process by which you would handle the flow of instructions and handle exceptions to that flow.

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys. 
I've previously made a version using an array, but the problem I'm having with that is I need to remove the a value that **isn't** either the simulated player guess, or the real hiding place (this could be the same number), and I'm unsure how to do it. 

Cheers for the input and advice